# Simply-connectedness condition in Levi-Malcev decomposition theorem

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a simply-connected, connected Lie group with solvable radical $R$. Then by **Levi-Malcev theorem** there is a closed semi-simple subgroup $S$ in $G$ so that $G=R\rtimes S$.

I want to show that the condition of simply-connectedness is essential. I found an example that  $GL_n(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C^*\cdot SL_n(\mathbb C)$ but $\mathbb C^*\cap SL_n(\mathbb C)\not =\{e\}$. I would like to understand this example, how to prove that the radical is  $\mathbb C^*$ and why the intersection is not the identity? Thanks!

Comment: For the intersection, how many roots does the polynomial $z^n-1$ have over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: As for the first question: what characterization of the radical do you know?